# Python multiprocessing - Return a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I'd like to parallelize a function that returns a flatten list of values (called "keys") in a dict but I don't understand how to obtain in the final result. I have tried:

```
def toParallel(ht, token):
    keys = []
    words = token[token['hashtag'] == ht]['word']
    for w in words:
        keys.append(checkString(w))
    y = {ht:keys}

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores)

token = pd.read_csv('/path', sep=",", header = None, encoding='utf-8')
token.columns = ['word', 'hashtag', 'count']
hashtag = pd.DataFrame(token.groupby(by='hashtag', as_index=False).count()['hashtag'])

result = pd.DataFrame(index = hashtag['hashtag'], columns = range(0, 21))
result = result.fillna(0)

final_result = []
final_result = [pool.apply_async(toParallel, args=(ht,token,)) for ht in hashtag['hashtag']]
```

Where toParallel function should return a dict with hashtag as key and a list of keys (where keys are int). But if I try to print final_result, I obtain only

> bound method ApplyResult.get of multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x10c4fa950

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
final_result = [pool.apply_async(toParallel, args=(ht,token,)) for ht in hashtag['hashtag']]
```

You can either use `Pool.apply()` and get the result right away (in which case you do not need `multiprocessing` hehe, the function is just there for completeness) or use `Pool.apply_async()` following by `Pool.get()`. `Pool.apply_async()` is **asynchronous**.

Something like this:

```
workers = [pool.apply_async(toParallel, args=(ht,token,)) for ht in hashtag['hashtag']]
final_result = [worker.get() for worker in workers]
```

Alternatively, you can also use `Pool.map()` which will do all this for you.

Either way, I recommend you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) carefully.

---

**Addendum:** When answering this question I presumed the OP is using some Unix operating system like Linux or OSX. If you are using Windows, you must not forget to safeguard your parent/worker processes using `if __name__ == '__main__'`. This is because Windows lacks `fork()` and so the child process starts at the beginning of the file, and not at the point of forking like in Unix, so you must use an `if` condition to guide it. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

---

ps: this is unnecessary:

```
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores)
```

If you call `multiprocessing.Pool()` without arguments (or `None`), it already creates a pool of workers with the size of your cpu count.